# Execute simple procedure call in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, nhibernate

I want to execute a simple MySQL stored procedure call in NHibernate, like this:

```
public void ExecuteProcedure(long idCell)
{
    using (ISession session = this.iSessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                string sQL = "call test(:idCell)";
                IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sQL);
                query.SetParameter("idCell", idCell);
                query.UniqueResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below, the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(IN `testing` BIGINT)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''

BEGIN
    select * from tbcell where id = testing;
END
```

This return the following Error:

```
could not execute query
[ call test(?p0); ]
  Name:idCell - Value:18
[SQL: call test(?p0);]
```

What's wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show the error detail?

Comment: Thank you for attention Najera. Unfortunately, there is no more detail in error window.

Comment: This command (theoretically) is correct? Or there are a best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys. I am accessing the database of a remote user, and a grant access for the stored procedures was needed (I thought grant access to schema only was enough). The nHibernate does not returned a error about permissions and, so, I didi'nt associate the problem to this. Sorry and thanks for attention.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE myDB.Test TO 'testUser'@'192.168.101.100';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```